# Saltstack load all files in pillars dir

Tags: salt-stack

I am having one large `.yml` config file, which gets loaded in pillar `.sls` file and later used in states. To refactor that config file and make it a bit readable, I would like to split it into multiple files, which would be placed in one directory.

**Current structure of pillars is:**

```
pillar
   |- app_configuration.sls
   |- config.yml
```

**Desired structure is:**

```
pillar
   |- app_configuration.sls
   |- config_files
      |- config1.yml
      |- config2.yml
      |- config3.yml
```

Current code in `app_configuration.sls` loads yaml file `config.yml` like this:

```
{% import_yaml 'config.yml' as app_config %}
```

But with updated configuration structure I need to pass directory path `config_files` and traverse all files in that directory and merge their content together. How can such behavior be achieved in Saltstack? The most important thing for me is how to list all files in `config_files` directory. I've already managed to create a for loop with merging code in Jinja, but when I try to use `salt.file.find` function with relative path (`config_files`), it does not work. Only when I specify absolute path, which is really really long and it does not look right for me. I also thought about enumerating those config files, but I would like to avoid that, because when new config is added, it may happen, that it is forgotten to be added in enumeration. That is not really scalable.

Comment: No matter what path you pick this sounds like a bad idea. and a good way of killing a masters performance. pillar should be nothing more then security settings. everything else should be handled with map files and defaults in the state tree. in the state tree you would also have access to cp.list_master which will allow you to create a list of files based on a prefix. from there it becomes simple loop.

Comment: Is this real issue when pillars gets rendered in matter of seconds now? I am just thinking of how huge performance impact it may have.

Comment: it is always a concern. pillar rendering is one of the hardest things a master does, and each minion calling for pillar data is a reason to re-render the pillar. so it can happen many times over in the coarse of a few seconds.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, it is definitely a good point.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for this, you can use `include` statement inside a pillar SLS file, or load files using `top.sls` pillar file.

Example of using `top.sls` for `base` environment for all minions:

```yaml
base:
  '*':
    - app_configuration
    - config_files.*
```

Or, without editing the `top.sls` file, `include` files from `config_files` directory in `app_configuration.sls`.

At the top of `app_configuration.sls`:

```yaml
include:
  - config_files.*
```

Another alternative is to use `map.jinja` files (see documentation on [Formulas](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/development/conventions/formulas.html)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the closest is the option with include. But as far as I know, include will include all configs into `app_configuration.sls`. What I am really looking for is to be able to access those configs, more precisely to merge them into one dictionary. So ideally somehow import all those configs into one variable. Is something like that possible?

Comment: I should have linked the documentation on [pillar](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/topics/pillar/#including-other-pillars). This has the details on merging, etc.

Comment: My bad, I probably did not express the problem corretly. Include will include all configs and it will merge them into one. But I need to do some processing on that merged conflict in Jinja. But Jinja gets rendered first before the `include` statement is processed.